# Break down this Rashi for me

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, sotah

I'd like to understand pshat in this Rashi. This is Sota, 2b.

Rashi reads as follows:

והא מדכתיב ״והיא לא נתפשה״ מכלל דפשיטא לך דנטמאה והיכי קאמר והיא לא נתפשה אועד אין בה נהי דרישה דקרא איכא למימר ע״י שנים עדים ושכב איש אותה בעדים ועד אחד אין נאמן בה אלא והיא לא נתפשה היכי קאי אאין נאמן בה הא אמרת דלא מחזקי לה בנבעלת

Answer (score 1, accepted):

והא מדכתיב ״והיא לא נתפשה״ מכלל דפשיטא לך דנטמאה

From the fact that it says והיא לא נתפשה we can infer that it is obvious to you that she was נטמאה

והיכי קאמר והיא לא נתפשה אועד אין בה

So how can you say that והיא לא נתפשה goes on ועד אין בה (because you are saying that והיא לא נתפשה means it is obvious that she is נטמאה but ועד אין בה means that we do not know if she was נטמאה)

נהי דרישה דקרא איכא למימר ע״י שנים עדים ושכב איש אותה בעדים ועד אחד אין נאמן בה

Although you can say that the beginning of the passuk is talking about where we have two witnesses, and ושכב איש אותה means with witnesses, so that one witness is not believed concerning her

אלא והיא לא נתפשה היכי קאי אאין נאמן בה הא אמרת דלא מחזקי לה בנבעלת

But what is והיא לא נתפשה going on? Will you say it is talking about testimony that is not believed concerning her, but you said that we do not assume she was נבעלה